# Avoiding getfield opcode

Tags: java, bytecode, opcode

In Java's String class, the *trim* method contains this:

```
int off = offset;      /* avoid getfield opcode */
char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */
```

I'm a bit puzzled by the comment *"avoid getfield opcode"*...

What does this mean? (I take it this avoids the use of *getfield* in the bytecode but why is this a Good Thing [TM]?)

Is it to prevent object creation in case *trim* doesn't do anything (and hence *this* is returned) or?

Answer (score 23):

My *guess* is that the point is to copy the values into local variables once, to avoid having to fetch the field value repeatedly from the heap for each iteration of the loop in the next few lines.

Of course, that begs the question as to why the same comment hasn't been applied on the "len" local variable. (I'd also expect the JIT to avoid refetching anyway, especially as the variables are final.)

Comment: The comment does not apply to 'len' because len is actively modified in the method, so it had to be a local variable anyway. 'off' and 'val' on the other hand aren't modified, but exist solely for optimization.

Comment: @Lars: Well spotted; I hadn't seen the change to len.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you personally were writing this library, do you expect you would have done this? Or simply relied on the JIT to micro-optimze?

Comment: @corsiKa: I'd have written the simplest code first, then profiled it. If that had suggested the micro-optimization, I *might* have applied it.

Answer (score 14):

`getfield` is used to get the member variable of a class.

As you can see from the remaining code:

```
while ((st < len) && (val[off + st] <= ' ')) {
    st++;
}
while ((st < len) && (val[off + len - 1] <= ' ')) {
    len--;
}
```

So when you're in a loop, it has to execute `getfield` every time you reference `value` or `offset`. You can incur a large performance-hit if the loop runs for a long time (because every time the loop-condition is tested, a `getfield` is exeuted for both `offset` and `value`). So by using the local variables `off` and `val`, you reduce the performance hit.

Comment: Agreed, except for this being valid only for non-optimized code. When JIT gets involved, it doesn't matter anymore. JIT does the optimization probably by putting value in a register; it's trivially allowed since it's fully equivalent. With value being final, this is obvious. But it'd possible even without it.

Comment: JIT *may* optimize this. Eg, don't expect this optimization on Dalvik. Pulling a field into a local can be useful for other reasons, such as a null check for a field that could be accessed concurrently.