# Java coding style on create new local variable to refer to class member variables

Tags: java, android, coding-style

This is a general coding style question regarding which style is more general or elegant.

When reading Java collection source code, I found the first style more frequently than the second one. Could anyone shred some light/ reasoning on this?  IMHO, the second style is more concise than the first one, but actually, the first one should be redeemed more elegant in some way I cannot argue.

1. creating local variable.

```java
private Set<K> keySet;

public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    if (ks == null) {
        ks = new KeySet();
        keySet = ks;
    }
    return ks;
}
```

2. operating on class member variable.

```java
public Set<K> keySet() {
    if (keySet == null) {
        keySet = new KeySet();
    }
    return keySet;
}
```

Comment: Which version of the source code are you looking at? All I can find is `return (ks = keySet) == null ? (keySet = new KeySet()) : ks;`. No second assignment to `ks`.

Comment: The version of source code does not matter. For your mentioned source code, why not writing it as: `if(keySet == null) keySet = new KeySet(); return keySet;`

Comment: @lucas The version of the source code *does* matter if you can't produce a version of the source code that actually contains what you allege it contains.

Answer (score 3):

It's an attempt at [micro-optimizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761681/avoiding-getfield-opcode) lazy initialization.

Since collection classes are used frequently, including in situations where high throughput is needed, the goal is to save as much time as possible.

---

The optimization attempted here is to lower the amount of `getfield` operations.

Since the set is only initialized once, we are worried about performance *after* initialization.

The 1st code block avoids a `getfield` by ensuring the check for `null` is local. **After the set has been initialized**, the 1st code block will *always* result in one `getfield` call, while the 2nd code block will *always* result in two `getfield` calls.

Comment: Great point, I guess this is the answer I am looking for. Great Thanks. @Vince Emigh 
 
>  JIT may optimize this. Eg, don't expect this optimization on Dalvik. Pulling a field into a local can be useful for other reasons, such as a null check for a field that could be accessed concurrently. – NateS Nov 22 '12 at 3:07